# parse ics files in bash to eliminate duplicates

Tags: bash, icalendar

My SOGo calendar crashed and I ended up with 5 different ics files from various devices that at one time were synchronized with the server.  The events in each file are mostly the same but there are some unique events in each file.  'm trying to make one ics file that contains all unique events in bash.
So far I've been able to eliminate duplicates that have the same UID with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a puids
while read -r p; do
    if [[ "$p" != *BEGIN:VEVENT* ]]; then
        echo $p
        #all lines on top of file are printed until the first event
    else
        #the else clause is executed at the start of an event
        read -r q
        #that's the next line which should be the uid
        if [[ -v puids["$q"] ]]; then
            # this uid has already been printed
            while [[ "$q" != *END:VEVENT* ]]; do
                read -r q
            done
        else
            echo $p
            while [[ "$q" != *END:VENVENT* ]]; do
                echo $q
                read -r q
            done
            echo $q
            #q should equal the end:vevent line
        fi
    fi
    while read -r p; do
        echo $p
    done
done < "$1"
```

Unfortunately this still results in some events being duplicated because different phones must have reassigned a different UID.  Any thoughts on how to use a bash array to eliminate these duplicate events?

Here is a sample from the ics file:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20200111T032850Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20200111T032850Z
DTSTAMP:20200111T023515Z
UID:15787101159003d6047c6800240939a4e21326acef35e@sufficientlysecure.org
SUMMARY:Sarasota
ORGANIZER:mailto:joedebby@dbr.jr
DTSTART;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/America/Cayman:20191230T0830
00
DTEND:20191230T213000Z
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DURATION:-PT60M
DESCRIPTION:Sarasota
X-EVOLUTION-ALARM-UID:b58c68f0b0cccdcce0692f54d5e066332559493d
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20200111T032943Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20200111T032943Z
DTSTAMP:20200111T022536Z
UID:1578709537738a2d30f66b6a1498cadbd3d4ff1f01d13@sufficientlysecure.org
SUMMARY:Sarasota
ORGANIZER:mailto:joedebby@dbr.jr
DTSTART;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/America/New_York:20191230T08
3000
DTEND:20191230T213000Z
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DURATION:-PT60M
DESCRIPTION:Sarasota
X-EVOLUTION-ALARM-UID:cfbc357d80d9e53ad0b0e60d63905add8ddf2cc1
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

As you can see the different phones each put in a different term for the same time zone, the start and end times are the same, however.  The UIDs are different so my script thought they were separate events.

Comment: It will help if you can post sample events that you want to eliminate: same event, but different UID. Without some input, hard to provide any feedback for the specific problem you have

Comment: Your code is very repetitive. Perhaps it could be refactored to just read stuff in one place, then decide what to do with that stuff based on a few state variables. Then "this is a UID" is just one more state to handle. If you do that, maybe also think about moving from Bash to Awk.

Comment: More fundamentally, I guess combine title, start time, and end time into a new key, and use that instead of the UID to identify events? That will still fail if something was edited but one device hasn't caught up and synchronized that particular event.

Comment: thanks, I'm not quite sure how to combine the variables into one key. Also, in the examples above with regard to time zone it's the same time zone only expressed differently.

Comment: I think what I really need is the c equivalent of a struct but the number of elements in an event is variable

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this python script](https://github.com/wotomg/icscleaner.py/blob/master/icscleaner.py) to remove duplicate enrty from calender file.

```
import sys

input_file = open(sys.argv[1])
output_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

the_text = input_file.readlines() # all text from input file

the_dict = {}
temp, eventid, header = "", "", ""


for line in the_text:
    if 'BEGIN:VEVENT' in line:
        break
    else:
        header += line

for line in the_text:
    if 'BEGIN:VEVENT' in line:
        temp = ""
        temp = line
    elif 'END:VEVENT' in line:
        temp += line.rstrip()
        the_dict[eventid] = temp
    elif 'DTSTART' in line:
        temp += line
        eventid = line
    else:
        temp += line

output_file.write(header[:-1]) # -1 for remove new line

for line in the_dict.values():
    output_file.write(line)

output_file.write('END:VCALENDAR')
```